# How to divide circle multipart nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, circles

I would like to get multi part node with vertical line between lower nodepart. Something like this:

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}  
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]  
\node [circle split,draw,double,fill=red!20]  
{  
$q_1$  
\nodepart{lower}   
{  
test1  
}  
{  
test2  
}  
};  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

What should i add to this to get vertical line between test1 and test2?

Comment: Okay, I've found solution . http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58993/how-create-circle-node-in-tikz-with-t-from-lines-inside-t-made-split-node-to-3

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".