# split a node into 3 parts

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to split a node into 3 parts: firstly split it vertically equally, then split the bottom one into 2 box horizontally and equally.

What's the best solution for such case in tikz?
Maybe we can just draw 3 box and align it carefully but the align task seems difficult for me:)

Below is a test code but it seems B and C not align bottom of A and not split equally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{box}=[draw, fill=pink!10, minimum width=5em, 
    text centered, minimum height=2.5em,drop shadow]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0cm,outer sep = 0pt]
    \node (A) [box,text width=10em] {A};
    \node (B) [box,below= of A.south west,anchor=west] {B};
    \node (C) [box,below= of A.south east,anchor=east] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output picture looks like below:

[image: not split equally]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! If you happen to need a circular node, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58993/how-create-circle-node-in-tikz-with-t-from-lines-inside-t-made-split-node-to-3

Comment: Using anchor=north west for B and anchor=north east for C will move B and C down.  But to fill the whole length you need to calculate how wide to make them, $0.5*(A.west) - 0.5*(A.east)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with minimal modification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{box}=[draw, fill=pink!10, minimum width=5em, 
    text centered, minimum height=2.5em,drop shadow]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0cm,outer sep = 0pt]
    \node (A) [box,minimum width=10em] {A};
    \node (B) [box,anchor=north west,minimum width=5em] at (A.south west) {B};
    \node (C) [box,anchor=north east,minimum width=5em] at (A.south east) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

problem with [your solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152356/43005) is that you want to control the size of the box which correspond to `minimum width`, but you instead use `text width` which controls the size of the content text rather than the box. Hence, the `text width` was padded by `inner sep`. Node `(B)` and `(C)` actually has the same size, but `(C)` was overlapping `(B)`.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect,great suggestion from all of you!

Below is a summarized version which correctly resolved my question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw, fill=pink!10, minimum width=5em, 
    text centered, minimum height=2.5em,inner sep=0pt}}

\newcommand{\trinode}[4] {%
    \node (#1) [box,minimum width=#4] {#1};
    \node (#2) [box,minimum width=0.5*#4,below=of #1.south west,
           anchor=north west] {#2};
    \node (#3) [box,minimum width=0.5*#4,below=of #1.south east,
           anchor=north east] {#3};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0cm,outer sep = 0pt]
  \trinode{A}{BBBB}{CCCC}{10em};
  \def\dx{2cm}
  \draw [red,shorten >=-\dx,shorten <=-.1*\dx] (A.south) -- (A.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The final output looks like below:

[image]